# iPhone Distribution: No profiles currently match

Tags: iphone, certificate, distribution, profile, code-signing

I am about to upload an app to iTunes Connect. I am not Team Agent, nor does it seem the Team Agent can make me a Team Agent. So he logged onto Member Center and downloaded a Distribution Certificate, which is in my Keychain along with the WWDR Certificate.

The bundle identifier is set to se."companyname"."appname".

When I set the Code signing identity to Distribution, it says no profiles match. Can only the Team Agent build the final apps for upload? How do I make XCode "use the right set of profiles"?

Any idea on how to get past this last hurdle? :)

Edit: can the Team Agent log onto Member Center and create a provisioning profile for the app, will that solve everything?

Answer: See Paul Peeleen's answer, I decided to add this additional information (too long for comment).

Paul, I'm going to mark yours as the correct answer, because it set me on the correct track... certificates are for the keychain (which is usually linked to a computer, or rather, a computer user's login, I guess).

A quite separate distribution profile must be created for the app - modifying an existing Development certificate to include the Team Agent only lets him develop. The little 'a-ha' or perhaps 'd'oh' moment was that it has to be created in the Provision section with Distribution tab selected (in the provisioning portal).

After that, in the Target Info/Build tab you just use the default automatic profile selector (dev/distro) and it's found automatically.

I also temporarily tried adding the 'gibberish' (f.ex. JX567ERNB.) before the se.companyname.appname for the Bundle Identifier, but the automatic profile selector told me that it shouldn't be there, I removed it and it worked!

The profiles are what enable the projects to use certificates in the Keychain, I guess.

Comment: hi, that was really annoying when I did it last time.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem by removing the generated bundle identifier prefix that I had gone to lengths to actually be able to add in xcode. Evereywhere I read it said it was part of the bundle identifier. A bit inconsistent I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked this with my accounts and it seems that only the team agent can create the stuff needed for AppStore or AdHoc releases.

IF you have the correct provisioning profile installed, and both your project settings and target setting for the "release" build are set to the correct provisioning profile. + that you have the correct certificates installed for that computer... you can build the release. 
I am unsure if only the Team Agent can upload these build, but otherwise you can package the release as a zip file (which you should anyways) and send it off the the team agent. The Team agent can then use the Application Loader to upload the application.

Comment: Forgot to +1 answers like I usually do if they are working and pertinent, as this one is. Indeed, the team agent needs to be in da house if any distribution is to occur ever. :p

Answer (score 27):

"iPhone distribution no profiles match" is one of the most annoying issue that I have ever had with app development.

This is how I sorted it out:

In Developer under iOS Provisioning Portal I needed to generate 4 certificates and download the WWDR intermediate certificate to be able to submit my app to the App Store:

1. Under Developer Certificate section ([link](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action)) generate a Developer Certificate. Also Make sure that you have the WWDR intermediate certificate installed, if in doubt download it from there.
2. Under Developer Certificate section ([link](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/distribute.action)) generate a Distribution Certificate (This is not that will show up in Xcode!)
3. Under Provisioning section ([link](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action)) generate a Development Provisioning profile certificate
4. Under Provisioning section ([link](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/viewDistributionProfiles.action)) generate a Distribution Provisioning profile. THIS WILL SHOW UP IN XCODE AS A DISTRIBUTION CERTIFICATE!

After that I was able to select the iPhone distribution profile generated at 4. Also make sure that your target settings are correct as they overwrite the project settings.

Your active provisioning profiles are listed under "Xcode/Organizer/Library/Provisioning Profiles"

I hope it helps

UPDATE: Some distribution provisioning profiles often just "disappear" from my list. So I have to download and install (just double click) them again from https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/viewDistributionProfiles.action not a big deal, but annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Also dont forget If you deleted all your certificates and keys in Keychain and you plan on regenerating those certificates make sure you change your certificate preferences in Keychain for Online Certificate Status Protocol to Off and Certificate Revocation List to Off, for some resaon this important step is the only way it worked for me.

## Another reason developer profiles are missing

While in organizer  under Library > Provisioning Profiles...
On my computer, if I hit Refresh, all the Distribution profiles are removed!!!
No big deal, just go back to your provisioning portal and go to Provisioning > Distribution and download the appropriate distribution profiles and your good to go! :)

Instructions right from apple... Follow them EXACT
https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action

> To request an iOS Development Certificate, you first need to generate
> a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) utilizing the Keychain Access
> application in Mac OS X Leopard. The creation of a CSR will prompt
> Keychain Access to simultaneously generate your public and private key
> pair establishing your iOS Developer identity. Your private key is
> stored in the login Keychain by default and can be viewed in the
> Keychain Access application under the ‘Keys’ category. To generate a
> CSR:
>
> In your Applications folder, open the Utilities folder and launch
> Keychain Access. In the Preferences menu, set Online Certificate
> Status Protocol (OSCP) and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) to “Off”.
>
> Choose Keychain Access -> Certificate Assistant -> Request a
> Certificate from a Certificate Authority. Note: If you have a
> noncompliant private key highlighted in the Keychain during this
> process, the resulting Certificate Request will not be accepted by the
> Provisioning Portal. Confirm that you are selecting “Request a
> Certificate From a Certificate Authority...” and not selecting
> “Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority with …”
>
> In the User Email Address field, enter your email address. Please
> ensure that the email address entered matches the information that was
> submitted when you registered as an iOS Developer. In the Common Name
> field enter your name. Please ensure that the name entered matches the
> information that was submitted when you registered as an iOS
> Developer. No CA (Certificate Authority) Email Address is required.
> The ‘Required’ message will be removed after completing the following
> step. Select the ‘Saved to Disk’ radio button and if prompted, select
> ‘Let me specify key pair information’ and click ‘Continue’.
>
> If ‘Let me specify key pair’ was selected, specify a file name and
> click ‘Save’. In the following screen select ‘2048 bits’ for the Key
> Size and ‘RSA’ for the Algorithm. Click ‘Continue’.
>
> The Certificate Assistant will create a CSR file on your desktop.

Comment: I only submitted two apps in my programming history. The first app when I was a new developer, took me 5 hours to get signed and sent to the apple servers. This time... only about 3 lol. This process is a huge pain in the ass when it doesn't work [hint to apple]

Answer (score 0):

I battled the problem all day too. Tried Tons of things.

*I downloaded the distribution provisioning profile. OK*

*Double Click. Into Keychain it goes (like magic) OK*

*Build. NOPE. Not Signed*

Check - it is not the Team Provisioning Cert that you are looking for it is the plain looking one that cannot be installed on devices.

If it is not there **you did not copy it to YOUR library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles folder.** *(just like I didn't)*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the case of your bundle identifier in the provisioning profile and your info.plist are the same.

I just had this problem, and resolved it finally when I saw that Xcode would not even let me manually select my distribution profile, saying 'profile doesn't match bundle identifier myappname'

When a took a close look, I saw that the bundle name had the app name capitalized, and the provisioning profile had the appname in all lowercase.