# iphone distribution (no profiles currently match) Madness

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing

I am a newbie and have been developing iOS apps for a about a year now. Last week my yearly certificate expired so I deleted all the provision profiles out of my Xcode and certificates and keys from my keychain on my macbook. I recreated everything again from scratch as outlined in these two posts. (including downloading new certificates and provisioning profiles from apples website)

[iPhone Distribution: No profiles currently match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608851/iphone-distribution-no-profiles-currently-match)
http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2012/01/10/ios-walkthrough-creating-your-certificates

So far so good. Ok, now for my iphone distribution Madness question. I have two approved apps in app store called "Alarm Touch" and "ABC lite". I opened up a Xcode project for my app "Alarm Touch" and when I looked under Code signing it had iphone distribution (no profiles currently match). So this is what I did.

- I logged into to https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles
- updated my distribution profile and under App ID I selected "Alarm Touch"
- hit submit
- refreshed the page
- Downloaded and doubled clicked on the distribution provisioning profile. It added it in my Xcode and under code Signing it was happy i.e. iPhone Distribution (Currently matches 'iPhone distribution)
- See this screenshot

[image]

- Now if I open another Xcode project called "ABC lite" its code signing distribution (no profiles currently match).
- Do I need to update my distribution profile every time and follow the above steps in order to release a code update to my existing approved app?
- I honestly didn't have to do these steps every time for each app update last year when my profile had not expired.
- What I am doing wrong or missing? Trust me I have been googling and reading up on existing posts on this topic on stackoverflow but can't find a solution to this wackiness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is really hocus pocus. I have no idea what I am doing yet it works.

- I had created another app id called TU7J43B8JP.* for an app name "iABC veryLite"
- Updated my distribution provisioning profile and selected this new iABC veryLite App ID
- Once updated I downloaded and doubled clicked this distribution profile
- Now all my apps in Xcode say iPhone Distribution (Currently matches 'iPhone distribution)

All working again. I wish apple will make this process somewhat easy ... Just a wish.

I hope this answer helps anyone in future.

Comment: That's a so called wildcard app id. It works for any app, but won't work for push notification, in-app purchase or icloud. So, very limited approach.

Comment: updated my post to reflect the wildcard app ids

Comment: @LordT, I used wildcard for only distribution provisioning profile. I do have many apps in appstore that use in-app purchases and local notifications that work just fine. I do create a unique App ID bundle for them but for distribution purposes I use this wild card TU7J43B8JP.*

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one provisioning profile. Just add another one for the second app id.
The way the system works:
You sign an app with your private developer/distribution key and a provisioning profile. For one Team account, only one Distribution Profile can be exist. But that Distribution Profile can have a number of Provisioning Profiles attached to it - one for each app.

When all Provisioning Profiles are installed, X-Code will automatically select the correct Provisioning Profile to use with that app.

If you want to save the hassle and avoid having to create a new Provisioning Profile for every app-id you use, you can create so called wildcard app-ids and can then create Provisioning Profiles for that.
The simplest wildcard is `.*`  - this matches every Appid.
We normally use things like `de.weptun.app.*` - which allows us to build all apps with a shared Begining of the App-ID.

**HOWEVER** Wildcard App-IDs have some major drawback, as they can't be used for nearly all surrounding services Apple provides:

- In-App Purchase
- Push Notifications (not sure about location notifications - those might still work)
- iCloud

So I would only use Wildcard App IDs if I were really sure I wouldn't need to use any of these services.

Comment: If I have lets say 70 approved apps then do I need a distribution provisioning profile created for each of them? That seems a lot of work. I had only one distribution profile last year that worked for all my app. I unfortunately I just don;t know how it magically worked?

Comment: see my answer below. I hope it helps other devs